# What is a proper way to create argument var names in a module for a new Class creation?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, paperjs

In the following code example I want to somehow create a var myThingName via a functions arguments so I can avoid having to build global var names outside of the Module.
I have tinkered with window['myvarname'] = "yada"; But that's a global and feels like a complete hack.

In short, I am assuming I need to have a way to make many vars like : myThingName_1 myThingName_2 etc...

Background: I am trying to build a Canvas Element constructor to put any number of individual Canvas elements onto the screen. I am using various libraries like Paper.js Kinetic.js etc. When trying to streamline the production I built a Module wrapper but am now stuck at how to create unique var names for the libraries KLASS constructor for their various implementations of stage or scope.

Perhaps I am doing things totally incorrectly from the start.
But at the moment I am stumped as to how this goes about or what the name of the pattern I am looking.

```
var MagicThingModule = {

    createThing : function(myThingNameAsString){
        var myThingName = myThingNameAsString;
        myThingName = new KLASS.Shape({ // code });
    },

    init : function(myThingNameAsString){
        createThing(myThingNameAsString);
    }
}

MagicThingModule.init("sendNameForThing_1");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var MagicThingModule = {
    allMyThings: {},
    createThing : function(myThingNameAsString){
        var myThingName = myThingNameAsString;
        myThingName = new KLASS.Shape({ // code });
        this.allMyThings[myThingNameAsString] = myThingName;
    },

    // use me to et your thing back...
    getMyThing: function(myThingName){
        return this.allMyThings[myThingName];
    },

    init : function(myThingNameAsString){
         createThing(myThingNameAsString);
    }
}
```

and you can later reference it by:

```
var myThing = MagicThingModule.getMyThing("sendNameForThing_1");
```

Comment: SWEEEEEET!!!! That did it! Thank you! Do you know the name of this pattern? Associative storing Array I guess but that does not seem like a good title.

Comment: I really don't know the name of this pattern or whether it is a pattern at all.. If you come across its name, please do comment... glad this helped you :)